# RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, youtube, live-streaming

I am trying to livestream a 24/7 looping stream from my Ubuntu server to youtube.

I have a gif that is looping and my music gets shuffled from a music list.

```
for i in ./*.mp3 ; do echo "file '$i'" ; done | shuf >mp3list.txt ffmpeg -f 
concat -i mp3list.txt -fflags +genpts -ignore_loop 0 -i giffilename.gif -f 
flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/(mykeyhere)
```

But I am getting this error when I run my script:

> RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header : Unknown error
>   occutredm/live2/(mykeyhere)

I did some research, but couldn't find anything about this specific error. I opened port 1935 and it did not change anything.

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 on a VPS.
Thanks for your help,

Dilie